# EVALUATE statement: Where does control pass to?

Tags: cobol, evaluate

I have a program with multiple (non-nested) `EVALUATE` statements.

The program is not behaving like I expect it to.

My suspicion is the `EVALUATE` statement. (I had a similar problem with a `SEARCH ~ END-SEARCH` in which control passes to the next sentence, not the next verb.) Is `EVALUATE` the same?  I've looked at IBM docs but can't find an answer.  I hope someone can help me with this.

In the code below, I want to know where control is passed to after the imperative statement of a `WHEN` clause has completed.

Here is a code snippet:

```
1000-PROCESS-TRANSACTIONS.
    PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-TRANSACTIONS                           
      EVALUATE TRUE                                             
        WHEN WS-TF-TXN-CODE = 'A'                               
          PERFORM 1000-ADD-RECORD THRU                         
              1000-ADD-RECORD-END                         
        WHEN WS-TF-TXN-CODE = 'C'                               
          PERFORM 1000-UPDATE-RECORD THRU                       
                  1000-UPDATE-RECORD-END                        
        WHEN OTHER                                              
          MOVE 'INVALID TXN CODE, TXN REC= ' TO WS-EF-ERROR-MSG 
          MOVE  WS-TF-DATA-AREA TO   WS-EF-DATA-AREA            
          WRITE ERROR-RECORD    FROM WS-ERROR-RECORD            
      END-EVALUATE                                              
      READ TRANS-FILE INTO WS-TRANS-FILE-REC                    
        AT END                                                  
          MOVE HIGH-VALUES TO EOTF-SWITCH                       
      END-READ                                                  
    END-PERFORM.                
1000-PROCESS-TRANSACTIONS-END.  
     EXIT.
```

In the preceding code, where does control pass to after:

- The `PERFORM 1000-ADD-RECORD THRU 1000-ADD-RECORD-END` when the `TXN-CODE is 'A'`
- The `PERFORM 1000-UPDATE-RECORD THRU 1000-UPDATE-RECORD-END`  when the `TXN-CODE is 'C'` and
- The `WRITE ERROR-RECORD FROM WS-ERROR-RECORD` when the`TXN-CODE is OTHER`.

Does control pass to the `NEXT SENTENCE`, i.e. after the `END-PERFORM` scope terminator; or, does control pass to the `READ` statement, i.e. after the `END-EVALUATE`?

Comment: I am receiving a FILE STATUS 46, reading beyond the end of file on the MASTER [not shown in this snipped.]  That says to me, that I'm never executing the READ TRANS-FILE; because, control is passing to:

Comment: For the above code to work, `READ TRANS-FILE` must be done once following `OPEN INPUT TRANS-FILE`. Did that `READ` happen?

Comment: The first read of both files executed.  The first trans rec had a TXN-CODE of C; the record was updated.  What's happening is the TRANS-FILE [in the snippet] is never being read again.  After the first update, I never get an = condition on the account number; because, the IO buffer has the first TRANS-FILE record in it.  I get repeated != condition.  Eventually the READ MASTER-FILE [in the 1000-UPDATE-RECORD routine] reads beyond EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Control *only* passes to `NEXT SENTENCE` if you explicit ask it to by using this (archaic = should not be used in any new code) statement. `NEXT STATEMENT` is a *jump* instruction "wherever the next period is".

The control flow of `EVALUATE` is the same as with `SEARCH` - the program goes on after the matching terminator `END-xyz`.

The "gotcha" is possibly in one of the `PERFORM ... THROUGH` which are coded within the `EVALUATE`:

- they may "jump around" anywhere, especially via `GO TO` so don't ever reach the coded `THROUGH`
- the paragraphs may not be in order and therefore may not ever reach the coded `THROUGH`

Comment: The 1000-UPDATE-RECORD-END is being executed.  The operation appears to go back and forth between the 1000-PROCESS-TRANSACTIONS and the PERFORM 1000-UPDATE-RECORD routines.  Based on your comment, it appears that EVALUATE behaves like the SEARCH verb; and, control passes to the next sentence, i.e. after the END-PERFORM, and not to the READ TRANS-FILE block which is immediately after the END-EVALUATE and which sets the switch that will cause the PERFORM to stop looping. I will try this again, inserting a GO TO and a  paragraph header just before the READ TRANS-FILE.

Comment: @NicholasM Simon is correct.  The EVALUATE statement will continue after the END-EVALUATE statement, and thus execute the READ statement.   Your problem is not in the EVALUATE statement -- it's elsewhere.